# Express closed set in Euclidean space

Tags: general-topology, lebesgue-measure

I know we have the Lemma that in Euclidean n-space, every open set is a countable union of disjoint open cubes plus a zero set, which is proved by using dyadic construction.

I'm wondering by the same construction, if the analogue holds for closed set, specifically, is this true that:

every closed set (in Euclidean n-space) is a countable union of almost disjoint cubes plus a zero set?

If not, what are some of the counterexamples?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "zero set" means a set of Lebesgue measure zero, the [Smith-Volterra-Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) is a counterexample. It contains no intervals (so there can be no cubes in your decomposition), but has nonzero measure.

Comment: Thank you. There's always something like cantor set lurking in the dark.